# Delphi "Free" TStringDynArray

Tags: delphi

Is there no need to free a TStringDynArray when created e.g. by SplitString? Attempts to free it fail as it is no object.

As I use it in a background process I am afraid that I create memory leaks by using it without explicitely freeing the memory.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, a [dynamic array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays) is managed by the compiler. It is reference counted and will be freed when the reference count drops to zero.

(However, if the elements of the array are (pointers to) objects, these objects will not be freed automatically. Only the array itself is freed. In your case, the elements are strings, and they are also managed by the compiler.)

But you may occasionally want to free the memory before the variables go out of scope. For instance, if you have a global variable which is a huge dynamic array, you can explicitly do a `SetLength(MyArray, 0)` or `MyArray := nil` or `Finalize(MyArray)` to let go of it.

Comment: Great, thanks for your Answer. As I only use strings I should be on the safe side!

Comment: @MichaSchumann Note that even if the elements are pointers to objects, that doesn't necessarily mean you need to free those objects when you dispose of the array. It highly depends on the nature of how they were created/managed. Perhaps there might be another more appropriate place to destroy them, such as if these objects are within more than one list/array, or otherwise referenced elsewhere, such as controls dropped on the form (in which case you shouldn't try to free them).

Comment: Thanks. For Objects I usually use the great TObjectList from Generics that helps a lot in avoiding memory leaks. Sometimes I am a bit jaleous on Java and Garbage Collection especially when a project has tight timel constraints ;-)

Comment: @MichaSchumann: I agree. The generic object list is great, and I use is a lot too. There's also a generic object dictionary.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, this I also use a lot. Things have become so easy If I compare to code of the Delphi 7 era...